# How do you create dependency injection objects with request scope when using Play framework?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

For example, let us say you want to inject a play controller with two datamappers (or repositories or whatever you want to call your database access classes) and each of those two datamappers should be injected with a JPA EntityManager. 
Then you want both datamappers to be injected with the same instance of EntityManager if their work should be done within the same transaction.

Maybe there is some Guice Custom Scope (request scope for the play framework) that can be used?
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes

Regarding a solution for JPA specifically, I have seen some code with helper method "play.db.jpa.JPA.em()" and annotation "play.db.jpa.Transactional" but I am now looking for a more generic answer about how to inject objects when you want the same instance to be reused within the request.

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: Play for Java version 2.4.6.

Comment: To my knowledge Play has no request scope build in (like in Spring or other similar frameworks). But mostly you don't need it.

Comment: By default in Play every thread has an EntityManager. At least in the docs suggest this (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/index.html?play/db/jpa/JPA.html). So if you don't do anything with multiple treads you should be on the safe side.